# How do animals with fur get enough sunlight to produce vitamin-D?

Tags: biochemistry, zoology

How is vitamin D synthesized in animals with fur; how do the cells get enough sunlight? If vitamin-D cannot be synthesized because of limited sunlight reaching the skin, do these animals have to obtain the vitamin from the diet or are there any alternate mechanisms of synthesis?